# Simultaneously running the same .m file with different inputs

Tags: scripting, linux

I have my *Mathematica* code in a `.m` file and I run it from the command line with some parameters. I was wondering, if there is no overlap in input and output files, can I run the same `.m` file simultaneously with different inputs? Will this create any problems? My code is pretty huge, so I don't want to try that unless I am sure.

I use the following command on the unix/linux commandline:

```
for i in $var
do
math -noprompt -script "scriptname.m" "parameter1" "parameter2"
done
```

I would like to run something like:

```
for i in $var
do
math -noprompt -script "scriptname.m" "parameter1" "parameter2" &
done
```

So that they would run in parallel. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible, and I do it routinely. The limitation is the number of kernels your license allows you to run simultaneously. This I believe is reported by `$MaxLicenseProcesses`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course you need to be careful not to write to the same files etc!

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed possible and I use this all the time. Instead of the `for ... & done` you might want to check out [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html). It's great for running parallel processes from the command line.
`parallel` can be told how many processes to run in parallel, so you don't run out of licences or memory. Here is an example:

```
parallel -j4 "math -noprompt -script scriptname.m parameter1 parameter2" ::: $var
```

where -jN tells how many parallel processes to run at once.

Pro tip for windows users: If you install [Git (for windows)](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit) you get a working native unix-like
environment based on msys (including bash and perl). By copying the parallel script (written in perl) to `GITINSTALLDIR\bin` everything just works.